# iOS11 Swift 4: Storing access rights for URLs retrieved from DocumentBrowserViewController

Tags: swift4, ios11, uidocumentbrowservc

When using `DocumentBrowserViewController` to access files from other applications, is it possible to store the access rights to those files?

### The concrete issue

Currently, for proof of concept purposes, I printed the url for a file, selected via `DocumentBrowserViewController`, to the console, hardcoded that url somewhere in my code and try to open that file again. That doesn't work because of: `{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}`

Now, is there a way to store the access rights?

In a blog post I found something using:

```
do {
    let data = try sourceURL.bookmarkData(
        options: URL.BookmarkCreationOptions.withSecurityScope,
        includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil,
        relativeTo: nil)
    print(data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

But `withSecurityScope` is "unavailable". (To be precise: `'withSecurityScope' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (Foundation.NSURL)`)

Is there a way to do this kind of stuff?

Regards and thanks in advance :)

### Edit

So maybe I was a little hasty with the question, the above code just needs to be adjusted into:

```
do {
    let data = try sourceURL.bookmarkData(
        options: URL.BookmarkCreationOptions.minimalBookmark,
        includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil,
        relativeTo: nil)
    print(data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And this data can then be used somehwat like that:

```
let url = try URL.init(resolvingBookmarkData: data, bookmarkDataIsStale: &stale)!
```

:)

Comment: You should read all of the information in the documentation for `DocumentBrowserViewController` and its delegate. There all kinds of info in there about needing `UIDocument` for `NSFilePresenter` and `NSFileCoordinator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a bookmark from the URL and store that. This is explained towards the 40' mark of this WWDC session: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/216 and is also in the Particles sample code published last week.

Essentially, the snippet above is correct, except that the `withSecurityScope` flag is useless on iOS (this is automatic). When resolving the URL on launch, you need to startAccessing or use UIDocument, which does this for you.